# How to use JSON sent via Express res.render in a public JS file

Tags: javascript, json, express, pug

Thanks in advance for your help.  I have a question that has been bothering me and I am sure it is absurdly simple.

On an `app.get` request I am calling an external api from express and then using `res.render` to send a jade file and the json.

I can successfully manipulate this data within jade files, and JavaScript written directly in the jade file.

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to manipulate this JSON from a JavaScript file referenced from the outputted HTML.

For example:

```
router.get('/dashboard', function (req, res, next) {

  // Call the external api and get data.
  // Parse the data

  res.render('dashboard', {
      data: data
  });

});
```

The dashboard.jade file then uses this data to do cool stuff.

```
if #{data.isNew} === true {do cool stuff}
```

I have also written some JavaScript that uses this data directly into the dashboard.jade file itself. But, I would prefer to write and use this JavaScript in a file called scripts.js that is referenced from the Jade file.

```
script(src='scripts.js')
```

I cannot access this data - I have tried multiple syntax to try to get it to work but have miserable failed.

My question is this, how do I work with JSON that has been res.rendered() to a view from within a JS file referenced from that rendered view?

Comment: Do you want to manipulate *data* before being sent to client ? And from external javascript instead writing it inline into *.jade* file ?

Comment: @Beau Any updates on how to do this?

Comment: still no answer for this, i have the same problem now lol

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a variable inside dashboard.jade that then uses [interpolation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation) to output the data into a string:

```
 script.
   var myData = #{JSON.stringify(data)};
```

The Jade engine will output that as a valid string that can then be used by any script loaded on that page.

Comment: He clearly says that he can do it inside the script tag in a jade file but what if you do script src='test.js' and he wants to access the variable inside test.js